# How to select multiple case in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am working on a project which used visual basic to write code in asp.net. I have some confusion when I am using the select case statement in asp.net. My asp.net is connected to sql server database, I have a table called `Person`, it has `Id` as decimal, `Name` as string and `Nationality` as string. In the table, it has some people had 2 nationality or above, I have case for `nationality`, for example, Mary have thai and vietnamese nationality, so i have written the code like this.

```
private sub Button1.Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles button1.Click

Dim a() as string

a = Me.DropDownList1.SelectedValue.Split(",".ToCharArray)

Select Case CInt(a(0))
    Case 1
        TextBox1.Text= "Vietnam"
    Case 2
        TextBox2.Text= "Thai"
    Case 3
        TextBox3.Text= "Australia"
    Case 4
        TextBox4.Text= "Canada"
End Select

End Sub
```

Sql server database Table:

```
Id    Name    Nationality
1     Mary    1,2
2     Andrew  4
3     Ken     3
```

Expected Result:

```
1 Mary Vietname,Thai
```

Comment: You can't use `Select Case` because it will match no more than one case. You could use multiple `If` statements, i.e. no `Else` so they all get processed.

Comment: You should fix the database: using CSV data only makes programming more difficult. All it needs is another table with columns for Id and Nationality, so Mary's Id would have two entries: `1 1` and `1 2`; Andrew would have only one entry in the table: `2 4`.

Comment: Using [ISO 3166-1 country codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_3166_country_codes) would be better. Try to use standards right from the start of a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've split the items, you can iterate over them, adding each piece of text to a List(Of String), then join them together at the end.

Perhaps somthing like:

```
Module Module1

    Public Function GetNationalityNames(csvIds As String) As String
        Dim natNums = csvIds.Split({","c}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        Dim natNames As New List(Of String)

        For Each nat In natNums
            Select Case nat
                Case "1"
                    natNames.Add("Vietnam")
                Case "2"
                    natNames.Add("Thai")
                Case "3"
                    natNames.Add("Australia")
                Case "4"
                    natNames.Add("Canada")
            End Select
        Next

        Return String.Join(", ", natNames)

    End Function

    Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine(GetNationalityNames("3"))
        Console.WriteLine(GetNationalityNames("1,2"))

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
Australia
Vietnam, Thai
```

(You'd declare the function to be `Shared`, but that was just a quick console program to demonstrate.)

Comment: I need to use Dropdownlist for the `a()`, Select Case must be `Select Case CInt(a(0))`

Comment: @user21834984 It's just an example of a function which you could use. You are expected to use it as a basis for writing your code. Why can you only use `a(0)`? You might as well give up the project now if there are ridiculous constraints like that imposed. It could be worked around, but it would be playing dumb.

Comment: i mean if i pick on other person on drop down list, it also have 2 nationality and it not the same, it might be `Canada and thai`